# nvd3 capture click event on stacked area chart

Tags: javascript, angularjs, nvd3.js, angularjs-nvd3-directives

I am trying to capture click event on a nvd3 stacked area chart. I am able to capture tooltip show tooltip hide events. I want to capture click event and get the clicked point info. Please help. [PLUNKER_LINK](http://plnkr.co/edit/MJYcOBd0UT0xWYuGujDb?p=preview)

my chart option is :

```
chart: {
                type: 'stackedAreaChart',
                height: 450,
                x: function (d) { return d[0]; },
                y: function (d) { return d[1]; },
                showValues: true,
                valueFormat: function (d) { return d3.format(',.4f')(d); },
                dispatch: {
                    tooltipShow: function (e) { console.log('! tooltip SHOW !') },
                    tooltipHide: function (e) { console.log('! tooltip HIDE !') },
                    beforeUpdate: function (e) { console.log('! before UPDATE !') },
                    elementClick: function (e) { alert('clicked');}

                }
            }
        };
```

Comment: Did you get it? You are using angularjs-nvd3 not angularjs-nvd3 directives..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap the `dispatch` block in a `stacked` block:

```js
stacked: {
    dispatch: {
        tooltipShow: function (e) { console.log('! tooltip SHOW !') },
        tooltipHide: function (e) { console.log('! tooltip HIDE !') },
        beforeUpdate: function (e) { console.log('! before UPDATE !') },
        elementClick: function (e) { alert('clicked');}
    }
}
```

But by doing so you still won't be able to receive `elementClick`, because stacked chart layer just won't send it. Instead you can receive the `areaClick` event, but it only gets trigged when you click *inside* the stacked area.

Therefore I would recommend you intercept dispatch events from the "interactive" layer. Just do it like this:

```js
chart: {
    type: 'stackedAreaChart',
    ...
    interactiveLayer: {
        dispatch: {
            elementMousemove: function(e) {
                console.log(e.mouseX + " " + e.mouseY + " " + e.pointXValue);
            },
            elementClick: function(e) {
                console.log(e.mouseX + " " + e.mouseY + " " + e.pointXValue);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you use interactive layer events, you couldn't get point info such as label, series and etc.

Comment: @SaeidZebardast of course you can - it has nothing to do with the interactiveLayer. Just declare an "api" attribute in your HTML nvd3 tag, and you'll be able to access your chart object and data series in JS. e.g. HTML `<nvd3 options='options' data='data' api='chartApi'></nvd3>`; and JS `var _chart = $scope.chartApi.getScope().chart; var pointIndex = nv.interactiveBisect($scope.data[0].values, e.pointXValue, _chart.x());`